# Why is float not a double on a 64-bit system?

Tags: c++, types

Considering an `int` will be 4 bytes on a 32-bit system and 8 bytes on a 64-bit system, why is `float` not treated the same? Why is size of a `double` != size of a `float` on a 64-bit system? Considering that the best native integer type is selected when I declare an `int` (which results in [higher performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1941826/368599)), shouldn't the same happen for `float` (which also results in a performance increase)?

Related question: Is it a bad idea to declare a type `my_float` (pardon the name!) that is `float` on 32-bit systems and `double` on 64-bit systems?

Comment: On most systems today (including x86), the efficiency of `float` is *not* dependent on 32/64-bit.

Comment: This is not an absolute; it's completely up to the compiler. Most compilers make `float` a 32-bit IEEE-754 floating point number, but the standard doesn't require this.

Comment: @Mysticial: Is that true? I was under the impression that typical compilers (with default settings) used SSE for `float` when compiling 64-bit code but not when compiling 32-bit code. (Because not all 32-bit CPUs support SSE3, but all 64-bit CPUs do.)

Comment: Why is an apple not a banana in a tropical country?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's a different story. I'm referring to the hardware. Regardless of whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit, the processor uses the same hardware to operate on `float`s and `double`s. 64-bit integers, on the other hand, would need to be emulated in 32-bit.

Comment: @Mysticial: If we're talking about the hardware, even most 32-bit CPUs today have support for native 64-bit integers. Heck, they have native support for 128-bit integers. It's *pointers* that track the CPU bitness, not integers. (Though that support is not nearly as good as "real" native 64-bit integers.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz On 32-bit x86, 64-bit integers are only accessible via integer SSE. Where's this 128-bit integer support? I'd love to be able to do arithmetic on 128-bit integers - it'd help a lot on the projects that I do.

Comment: @Mysticial You can access 64-bit integers via normal instructions, they just are implemented as two side-by-side 32-bit integers. SSE is not required.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan That counts as emulating in my definition. Since it's no longer 1 instruction and you have to rely on carry flags and such.

Comment: @Mysticial: 128-bit register support is part of [streaming SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions#Integer_instructions). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5eawz414%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) too. They're pretty sparse though.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's just the register size. I wouldn't really consider bitwise and byte-shifts as "integer support". It'd at least need to have a 128-bit addition/subtraction for it to be usable in any 128-bit arithmetic.

Comment: C has exactly 3 predefined floating-point types: `float`, `double`, and `long double`. Typical hardware these days has 3 floating-point formats: 32 bits, 64 bits, and something a bit bigger than 64 bits (usually 80, 96, or 128). Making `float` 64 bits would make the 32-bit floating-point format inaccessible. (I've worked on systems with 64-bit `float`, but they didn't have 32-bit floating-point at all.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: I wish C had a better set of floating-point types, even if on many systems some would alias each other.  On a 16-bit or 32-bit machine with no FPU, for example, chaining operations using intermediate-result types with whose mantissas were 32 bits or 64-bits *without an implied '1'* may be much faster than using types whose mantissa is 23+1 or 52+1 bits, but extended precision is only good when a language supports it.  IMHO, C should have specified that operations on `float` yield result type `long float`, which could then be 32, 48, 64, 80, 96, or 128 bits as convenient.

Comment: Think about array of 1 million floats or doubles. The difference is 4MB memory. Also, even on 64-bit systems exist 8 and 16 bit registers/variables.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your question is based on a false premise. On most modern 64-bit systems, `int` is still 4 bytes. Why consume twice as much memory and twice as much memory bandwidth when such large integers are so rarely needed? On typical modern 64-bit systems, math on 64-bit integers is not faster than math on 32-bit integers, so there's no benefit to be had.

Comment: Was gonna say exactly this--`int` isn't 64 bits on any system I've encountered! It's within standard to have a 64-bit-wide `int` type, but it's just not bothered with since compiler designers can/do widen `long` and `long long` first.

Comment: `__int64` is twice the size of `int`, right? Maybe the OP is confused there, and thinks all `int`s on a 64-bit system are `__int64`?

Comment: @WendiKidd: You are right. I was under the impression that on 64-bit systems `int` size was 8 bytes, the native word size. Also, it has to be able to store a pointer address, no?

Comment: `__int64` is a) a Microsoft extension, and b) only twice as wide as `int` by virtue of coincidence. It is defined as 64 bits wide, while `int` is (on 32-bit and 64-bit MSVC++ platforms) defined as 32 bits wide, and the two are not related.

Comment: @Samaursa: Nope. `int` has no special requirements like that, only that it be at least as wide as `short` and not wider than `long`.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan I know, I was just taking a guess at where the OP's confusion was stemming from :)

Comment: @Samaursa: There is no requirement that `int` be able to store a pointer address.

Comment: Using `int` as an array index is one of the biggest 64-bit portability issues I find when I'm porting 32-bit code to 64-bit. I lot of old code that I stress-test at 16/32+ GB of data-size simply breaks because of integer overflow. Not everyone has the habit of using `size_t` instead of `int`.