# x64 much faster than x86 in Windows 7 64-bit, why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

I wanted to create a very basic app to test 64 bit vs 32 bit performance just to see which one runs best on my computer.
To my surprise, I found that x64 was about 3 times faster than x86.
I used VS 2012 Ultimate compiled for release and run as a standalone app without debugging.
This is a WinForm application with a button and 2 text boxes.
In the x64 version takes about 120 ms to complete, while the x86 build takes about 350 ms.
Also, if I change the data types to say Int64 from int then both code paths become about 3 times slower.

I know that x64 runs native on 64 bit windows and 32 bit is converted through WoW, but online comparisons show that 32 bit on 64 run without a significant performance penalty unless it is with an Itanium CPU which I do not have.

Another possibility is that the VS2012 compiler is just much more optimized for x64, but is 3x performance difference reasonable from generic VS optimizations?

Either way, it seems that I would much better off compiling to x64 on my machine whenever possible.
Can anybody give me any simple cases where x86 may be better?

Here is my test code.

```
    DateTime startTime;
    DateTime stopTime;
    int waitValue;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string startText = textBox1.Text;
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(startText, out value))
        {
            waitValue = value - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            value = 1000000;
            waitValue = value - 1;
            textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
        }

        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < value; ii++)
        {
            shortProcess(ii);
        }
    }

    private int shortProcess(int value)
    {
        int startValue = value;
        int useVal = startValue;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 1000; ii++)
        {
            useVal = ii;
        }
        useVal = startValue;
        checkValue(useVal);
        return useVal;
    }

    private void checkValue(int value)
    {
        if (value >= waitValue)
        {
            stopTime = DateTime.Now;
            //textBox2.Text = (stopTime.Ticks - startTime.Ticks).ToString();
            textBox2.Text = (stopTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a comment - as far as I know if you run a 64bit app under the 64bit version of Windows, that's "native", but if you run a 32bit application from the same version of Windows, it has to be translated so the 64bit architechture can read it properly, this might not impact anything regarding your code, just thought it would be worth mentioning

Comment: "I am wondering if these results are typical and if you can post your results" - We are not a test benching community and unlikely you will be flooded with sample data. Besides, you would need to know processors, OS, configurations, blah, blah. Also, your sample code is not great for bench marking either and you may want to check you really are testing just one thing (which you are not).

Comment: Chances are good that what you're seeing is the result of the x64 JIT optimizer being superior (in this artificial test case, at least) to the x86 JIT optimizer. This could be an acceptable question if you [edit]ed to ask for an *explanation*, rather than attempting to conduct a poll.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343812/64-bit-performance-advantages/3343991

Comment: I edited the code to be more of a question as suggested. I have seen that other post and a few others, but every one has been very generic without any testable conclusions. I also don't know if this is limited to my machine or simply to VS 2012 which is why I am looking for confirmation or anything I can do to improve my test.

Comment: I initially though I would see no difference and then I would add more math to see at what point if any one path would become faster.

Comment: I wouldn't put much stock in a benchmark like this.

Comment: Can you give me a basic example of what would be a good benchmark?

Comment: I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941826/why-is-this-faster-on-64-bit-than-32-bit?rq=1 which talks about a very similar situation. Should I just close out this question and point to that thread?

Comment: @Alex - The x64 platform supports running native x86 (32-bit) code. There's no emulation or translation of the code itself, although there is a "Windows on Windows 64" (aka WOW64) layer that handles the operating system interop with 32-bit apps. There's not a significant performance difference in small programs.

Comment: The question you found looks like a reasonable duplicate to me. I went ahead and closed your question, overriding the 4 "off-topic" votes it had accumulated. Those were nonsensical as far as I'm concerned. This is clearly a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar question has been answered here: [Why is this faster on 64 bit than 32 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941826/why-is-this-faster-on-64-bit-than-32-bit?rq=1)

That test is more complex, with some more math, but the results are similar and even more extreme than mine, which means that x64 is the way to go.

Comment: Correction: x64 *can* be the way to go. It is not *always* a performance win. There are tradeoffs, as with any engineering decision. For example, pointers are larger in the 64-bit world, which means a larger memory footprint. The ceiling is higher, of course, but so is the pressure. Not to mention the *cache*, which is the same size, and therefore fills much more quickly. x64 is almost always faster when you're working with types that are 64-bits wide, but it's rare that normal applications need so many bits. With only 32 bits, the performance difference is minimal. You must *test* to be sure.